# Get the width and height of a rectangular polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, spatial-query

I have a table with point features saved in the my PostgreSQL database, and I can run the following query to get the extent of the point features and I turned the extent back into a geometry:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(pts.geom), 4026)) AS Extent_Geom 

FROM Table_w_Point_Features pts
```

Here is how the output geometry of a rectangle polygon that represents the extent of the point features looks like:

```
POLYGON((-117.536012078 33.7130048820001,
         -117.536012078 34.3860049530001,
         -116.825011941 34.3860049530001,
         -116.825011941 33.7130048820001,
         -117.536012078 33.7130048820001))
```

Is there any way in PostGIS that I can get the Width and Height of the extent that I created above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd go with the `Geometry` [Accessors](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors) for `X` to give width: [ST_XMax](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_XMax.html) - [ST_XMin](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_XMin.html), and the related functions for `Y` for height.

Comment: I see your point, and I can use the Maximum and Minimum coordinates returned to calculate the width and length. Thanks!

Comment: what if your rectangle was tilted at an angle? The max x - min x would give a measurement that is too long.

Comment: The question is about an extent of points, the rectangle is the extent and therefore will not be tilted.